# afterTransactionCompletion not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I created an hibernate interceptor :

```
public class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

private boolean isCanal=false;

public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable arg1, Object[] arg2, String[] arg3, Type[] arg4) throws CallbackException {

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        System.out.println("Inside MyInterceptor(onSave) : "+entity.toString());
    }
    if(entity instanceof Canal){
        isCanal=true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx){
    if(tx.wasCommitted()&&(isCanal)){
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            System.out.println("Inside MyInterceptor(afterTransactionCompletion) : Canal was saved to DB.");
        }
    }
}
```

but the method afterTransactionCompletion doesn't get executed after a transaction is commited. I've tried all the ways I know of but I can't make it work. What's more surprising is that the onSave method works fine.

Help !

```
Could this be due to this bug ? :
http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1956
```

**How can I circumvent this bug if it's the cause ?**

Answer (score 0):

What is the signture of afterTransactionCompletion supposed to be? In the documentation I found it says:

```
void afterTransactionCompletion(boolean successful, Transaction tx)
```

In which case it's no surprise your method is not called.

I think if you use the @Override annotation you would be warned by the compiler that you've got the signature wrong.

Comment: I used this documentation : https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html#afterTransactionCompletion(org.hibernate.Transaction) .

It seems that we're not using the same doc. plz, explain.

Comment: well I just googled. However the key point is to look at the EmptyInterceptor's signature - does your signature match?

Comment: I used the @Override annotation.my signature does match the EmptyInterceptor's signature.